# Inexplicit "run at startup" permission request after updating to play-services-ads:19.5.0

Tags: android-studio, permissions, dependencies, google-play

My app has started requesting the "run at startup" permission ever since I upgraded to play-services-ads:19.5.0. Building the exact same code, no changes to manifest, but with play-services-ads:19.4.0 proves that it's the dependency causing this, because the permission does not get requested anymore.

Anyone else having this problem?

Comment: Yes. I found your question when trying to work out what's causing the new permission, then realised that's the only change I made from 19.4.0 to 19.5.0.

Comment: I am also facing this issue, users are writing 1 star reviews just because they don't like this permission. Did you find any solution? Is this permission even required? I have upgraded to newer Unity AdMob plugin that uses 19.5.0, this permission is so annoying.